# Display date + 3 months using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, date

I have inherited a form that has some existing JavaScript that creates a new date + 3  months from today's date.

```
var monthAway = new Date(new Date);
var day =monthAway.getDate();
var month =monthAway.getMonth() + 3;
var year =monthAway.getFullYear();
$('#Date_for_Second_Store_Access_to_Expire').val(day + "/" + month + "/" + year);

<p><input id="Date_for_Second_Store_Access_to_Expire" type="hidden" name="Date_for_Second_Store_Access_to_Expire" class="required" /></p>
```

Issue is that if today's date is in October, November or December new date month will be 13, 14 or 15 rather than updating the to 1, 2 or 3 and then updating the year, e.g. 5/11/2014 is 05/14/2014 rather than 05/02/2015.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can use 'addMonths()' on the date object like ' var day = new Date().addMonths(3);'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add 3 months to `monthAway` variable using [setMonth method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_setmonth.asp) as below

```
monthAway.setMonth(monthAway.getMonth() + 3);
```

then simply use the modified `monthAway` to display the expiration date. Please note that [getMonth() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getmonth.asp) will return 0-11 where 0 is January, 1 is February, ... , 11 is December, so you need to do this to display the correct month

```
var month = monthAway.getMonth() + 1;
```

This is the complete modified code, the value of `#Date_for_Second_Store_Access_to_Expire` would be `5/2/2015` assuming the code is executed today (`5/11/2014`).

```
var monthAway = new Date(new Date);
monthAway.setMonth(monthAway.getMonth() + 3); // add 3 months to monthAway

var day = monthAway.getDate();
var month = monthAway.getMonth() + 1; // add 1 because .getMonth returns zero based month
var year = monthAway.getFullYear();
$('#Date_for_Second_Store_Access_to_Expire').val(day + "/" + month + "/" + year);

<p><input id="Date_for_Second_Store_Access_to_Expire" type="hidden" name="Date_for_Second_Store_Access_to_Expire" class="required" /></p>
```

This is the JSFiddle that shows the value of `day + "/" + month + "/" + year` from the above code: http://jsfiddle.net/jwa6o6r2/

Comment: Thanks for this, works perfectly! Good to know that I wasn't far off

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
    var x = 3; //or whatever offset
var CurrentDate = new Date();
CurrentDate.setMonth(CurrentDate.getMonth() + x);
alert(CurrentDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do a simple check when increasing the `month` variable:

```
 var month = monthAway.getMonth() + 3;
 if(month > 12) //If it crosses 12, start from 1 again.
   month -= 12;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
var month = monthAway.getMonth() + 3;
```

To

```
var month = ((monthAway.getMonth() + 3) % 12) + 1;
```

The `((monthAway.getMonth() + 3) % 12)` will give you a number from 0 to 11. Since you want 1 - 12, that's where the `+ 1` comes in.

For the year issue, try the following

```
var year = (month <= 3 ? monthAway.getFullYear() + 1 : monthAway.getFullYear());
```

This will check if the month is less than or equal to 3, which would only be possible if you've wrapped around.

Comment: That works well thanks. Any idea how I also get the year to update from 2014 to 2015?